# Since nothing was done about this flag that is plagiarism, should I just suggest an edit?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, plagiarism

I had flagged this answer here because it appeared to be plagiarism: [see post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27468996/3757322). The user appears to have simply copied and pasted the answer from this site [here](http://cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson14.html), starting with the line:

> The full declaration of main looks like this:

My flag was marked as helpful, but then nothing appears to have happened. What should be done next on my part? Should I just suggest an edit with the referenced site? Or should I have done that first before flagging? Or is there a specific reason nothing happened? The answer doesn't have a lot of positive votes, but it's more the principal of the thing, since this post could be taking away from the original writer's site and not provide any credit at all. The question has significant traffic (68k views in 5 years).

Comment: I think i would have started by *nicely* asking the answerer to add attribution and linking to the source. In this case it seems to be a user that is still active.

Comment: @KevinB Now that I look back, I probably should have started that way in the first place :-) They probably didn't realize what they were doing...

Comment: There are not an enormous number of ways to document the arguments to the C language's main() function, 3! is not that big a number..  After **thousands** of questions about it, 1820 of them tagged with [ main] right now, 1820 > 6 dictates that somebody is going to repeat the same answer.  It appears somehow inevitable that somebody is going to repeat the same *question* over and over and over again.  Kill me now.

Comment: @Hans, we won't. Come on, let's get some tea.

Comment: Had some before I considered posting that comment, then discovered that [ main] without a space triggered somebody's genial idea to turn that into [main].   Tea didn't cut it.

Comment: @HansPassant he copied his entire answer, verbatim, from some website.  He also admits to doing similar before, but with attribution.  As in, "Here's my new book, it's called The Great Gatspy.  Don't worry, I've added an attribution to Fitzgerald at the end of the book." That shit don't fly.